# How to set varible envirement in global level(for entire envirement)?

Tags: 14.04, environment-variables

i need to set this line

```
export STUDIO_JDK=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

according [the documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration) to setting file... i have try this command to open system file

/etc/environment

but get this

```
aleksey@aleksey:~$ sudo /etc/environment
[sudo] password for aleksey: 
sudo: /etc/environment: command not found
```

How i can make it work?

Comment: Did you mean `sudo nano /etc/enviroment` ?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run `/etc/environment` as a command. If you want to edit it, you can use `nano` or `vim` (if you are beginner I would recomend nano).

Type `STUDIO_JDK=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` inside and press Ctrl+O to save, then Ctrl+X to exit nano.

Comment: If OP's editing `/etc/environment`, `export` shouldn't be used.